# append de jquery no funciona cuando mi select tiene la clase y atributo "class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-live-search="true""

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

tengo un select que abro dentro de un div

```
    $('#select-subcategoria').on('change', function() {
    var texto_seleccionado = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    if (texto_seleccionado == 'Calzado') {
        var select = $(
            '<div id="talle" class="form-group">'+
                '<label for="">Talles</label>'+
                '<select id="mySelect" name="talle[]"'+
                      'class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-live-search="true">'+
                      '<option class="XS" selected>XS</option>'+
                      '<option class="S">S</option>'+
                      '<option class="M">M</option>'+
                      '<option class="L">L</option>'+
                      '<option class="XL">XL</option>'+
                      '<option class="XXL">XXL</option>'+
                '</select>'+
            '</div>');
        $("#campo").append(select);

    }
});
```

pero simplemente no se porque razon no me abre en el div... pero si comento esta linea de codigo`'class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-live-search="true">'+` y lo dejo asi

```
var select = $(
        '<div id="talle" class="form-group">'+
            '<label for="">Talles</label>'+
            '<select id="mySelect" name="talle[]">'+
                  // 'class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-live-search="true">'+
                  '<option class="XS" selected>XS</option>'+
                  '<option class="S">S</option>'+
                  '<option class="M">M</option>'+
                  '<option class="L">L</option>'+
                  '<option class="XL">XL</option>'+
                  '<option class="XXL">XXL</option>'+
            '</select>'+
        '</div>');
    $("#campo").append(select);
```

funciona sin problemas... la verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal... alguna ayuda?
PD: estoy usando una libreria de boststrap llamada bootstrap select

Comment: ahora descubri que el atributo multiple es lo que hace que no funcione...

Answer (score 0):

$('#mySelect').selectpicker('refresh'); agregar esto fue mi solucion.!